# spoj Mixtures : Need help regarding logic

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

The question asks to minimise the smoke produced.

My approach: 
Since at any instant, only adjacent mixtures will be picked up. So i tried using dp. As in if i know the answer for n-1 mixtures, i can get the answer for n mixtures.

How?:
The nth mixture will either be

Case1:mixed with (n-1)th mixture and their result mixed with resultant mixture of 1st n-2 mixtures. OR

Case2: It will be mixed the resultant mixture of n-1 mixtures.

Let dp[i] denote minimum smoke for first i mixtures and res[i] denote resultant mixture for first i mixtures. They will contain optimised values ofcourse. And A[i] denote the color of i th mixture

so

for Case1: dp[i]=dp[i-2]+ A[i-1]*A[i] + res[i-2]*(A[i-1]+A[i])%100;
 And res[i]=(res[i-2]+A[i]+A[i-1])%100;

for Case2: dp[i] = dp[i-1] + res[i-1]*A[i];
 and res[i] = (res[i-1]+A[i])%100;

Base cases:

if only 1 mixture given smoke = 0 and resultant mixture is mixture itself.
and if only 2 mixtures given smoke = A[0]*A[1] and resuilt = (A[0]+A[1])%100

My code: out of 4 cases, it passed only 1 ( not the sample test case)
Where is my logic wrong?

#### Problem Statement

Harry Potter has n mixtures in front of him, arranged in a row. Each mixture has one of 100 different colors (colors have numbers from 0 to 99).

He wants to mix all these mixtures together. At each step, he is going to take two mixtures that stand next to each other and mix them together, and put the resulting mixture in their place.

When mixing two mixtures of colors a and b, the resulting mixture will have the color (a+b) mod 100.

Also, there will be some smoke in the process. The amount of smoke generated when mixing two mixtures of colors a and b is a*b.

Find out what is the minimum amount of smoke that Harry can get when mixing all the mixtures together.

Input
There will be a number of test cases in the input.

The first line of each test case will contain n, the number of mixtures, 1 <= n <= 100.

The second line will contain n integers between 0 and 99 - the initial colors of the mixtures.

Output
For each test case, output the minimum amount of smoke.

#### Example

Input:

```
2
18 19
3
40 60 20
```

Output:

```
342
2400
```

```
 #include<bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main() {
        int n;
        cin>>n; //no. of mixtures
        int A[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            cin>>A[i]; // filling their values.
        if(n==1)  //base case
        {
            cout<<0<<endl;
            return 0;
        }
        long long dp[n],res[n];
        dp[0]=0;                     // for 2 mixtures
        res[0]=A[0];
        dp[1]=A[1]*A[0];
        res[1]=(A[1]+A[0])%100;     //
        for(int i=2;i<n;i++)        
        {
            long long ans1,ans2,res1,res2;

            ans1=dp[i-1]+res[i-1]*A[i];
            res1=(res[i-1]+A[i])%100;

        ans2=dp[i-2]+A[i-1]*A[i]+res[i-2]*((A[i-1]+A[i])%100);
            res2=(res[i-2]+(A[i-1]+A[i])%100)%100;

            dp[i]=min(ans1,ans2);
            if(dp[i]==ans1)
                res[i]=res1;
            else
                res[i]=res2;    
        }
        cout<<dp[n-1];
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code outputs 6500 for input `20  10  30  30  40` but the correct result is 3500:

```
20  10  30  30  40
200/30  900/60
  30      60    40
          2400/0
  30      0

smoke = 200 + 900 + 2400 = 3500
```

One trick is to realise (or learn) that the final colour for any collapsed interval is the same, no matter the order of mixing on it. The Python code below, utilising divide-and-conquer, was accepted.

We can use two ideas (1) any specific interval we choose to collapse all the way to one element by mixing will result in the same colour no matter the order of the mixes because of the associative property of addition, and (2) given an optimal mix order for any interval (in particular the full list), because mixing is between adjacent colours, there must be some optimal single place for the last mix of that interval, in other words a single optimal place that divides the full interval in two such that each side is fully collapsed before the final mix.

Given those two ideas, we basically build a kind of "brute force" recurrence -- try each one of those possible splits, knowing that the colour for each part is not a dimension we need more than one possibility for, and perform the same recurrence on each of the two parts. Hopefully, the base cases in the code are pretty clear.

```
import sys

# Returns (smoke, colour)
def f(lst, i, j, memo):
  # Empty interval
  if i > j:
    return (float('inf'), 0)

  # Single element
  if i == j:
    return (0, lst[i])

  if (i, j) in memo:
    return memo[(i, j)]

  best = (float('inf'), -1)

  for k in xrange(i, j):
    smoke_l, colour_l = f(lst, i, k, memo)
    smoke_r, colour_r = f(lst, k + 1, j, memo)
    smoke = smoke_l + smoke_r + colour_l * colour_r
    colour = (colour_l + colour_r) % 100
    best = min(best, (smoke, colour))

  memo[(i, j)] = best
  return best


# I/O
while True:
  line = sys.stdin.readline()
  if line:
    n = int(line)
    if n == 0:
      continue
    lst = sys.stdin.readline()
    lst = map(int, lst.split())
    print f(lst, 0, n-1, {})[0]
  else:
    break
```

Comment: coudl u explain in detail about the approach?

Comment: @chaitanya_12789 sure, I added more information in the answer.